# How to use .retry of superagent in React js?

Tags: reactjs, superagent

I'm posting this here because I couldn't find a good example/documentation on this subject. The official Supergent docs only say

> This method has two optional arguments: number of retries (default 3) and a callback. It calls callback(err, res) before each retry. The callback may return true/false to control whether the request sould be retried (but the maximum number of retries is always applied).

I have the following questions regarding this functionality.

1. What happens if there are no callback to the retry method eg: `request.retry();` how does it decide when to retry?
2. Does the `true/false` returned by the callback function decide whether to retry again?
3. Is there a way to skip retrying if the request failed with specific error type, say 5xx?
4. How can you have an async function as the callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. The code documentation says that retry is called under the following conditions:

```
/**
 * Set number of retry attempts on error.
 *
 * Failed requests will be retried 'count' times if timeout or err.code >= 500.
 *
 * @param {Number} count
 * @param {Function} [fn]
 * @return {Request} for chaining
 * @api public
 */
```

2. Yes, return `true` to retry, `false` to not retry
3. Yes, you can pass `(err, res)` into the callback and program that into the callback logic and return `false` on the desired error code.
4. Upon my testing, no, you cannot use an `async` function as the callback to `retry`. It fails to retry. This would be a nice feature.